# Nodemon showing restarting but actually not

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using nodemon in dev mode.Whenever I make any changes to the file, nodemon displays it is restarting due to changes but actually doesn't. If I visit the webpage ie. localhost:3000, I am getting back the same page with a 304 response. Why is that?

```
const app=express()

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}))
app.listen(3000)

app.get('/',((req,res)=>{
    res.send(`<a href="/login">Login</a> 
              <a href="/register">Register</a>
              `)
}))
```

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't restart your server?  Did you add a `console.log()` message when your server starts so you can actually see it?

Comment: @jfriend00 it runs the first time. But if I make any edits, even if i add a console.log , the terminal shows that nodemon is restarting due to changes, but neither the changes nor the console.log message is displayed. Browser giving a 304 response on refresh.

Comment: What is this: `app.use(urlencoded({extended:false}))`?  Shouldn't it be `app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}))`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Actually it was a typo. sorry. Recently I upgraded my os to windows 10 from 8.1. anything to do with that? It was working fine on 8.1

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is in your code, not nodemon**

Add this line at the end:

```js
app.listen(3000)
```

Don't forget to set routes (etc...) before listening

Comment: still not working. the problem is changes are not reflected in the browser and getting a 304 response when i should be getting a 200

Comment: it's not about windows version, can you edit your code to edited one?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with the latest version of nodemon. I installed an earlier version (2.0.1) and now it is working fine. The latest version (2.0.9) was released yesterday and there seems to be some kind of bug.